# Get serial number of created PKPass on PassSlot.com server

Tags: ios, passbook, passslot

How can I retrieve the serial number of a pass from [passslot](/questions/tagged/passslot)? I have generated the pass using the following code:

```
[PassSlot createPassFromTemplateWithName:@"Membership Card" withValues:values andRequestInstallation:self completion:^{
    NSLog(@"Pass!");
}];
```

Or How can I display a pass on my `UIViewController` or `PKAddPassesViewController` if I have the serial key of the pass as I can generate the pass from following API:

```
https://api.passslot.com/v1/templates/names/templatename/pass
```

I'm using the Passslot.com API for Passbook Passes, any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you can get the pass serial number:

```
[PassSlot passFromTemplateWithName:@"PassSlot Demo" withValues:values pass:^(PSPass *pass) {
    NSLog(@"Serial Number: %@",pass.serialNumber);
    [PassSlot requestPassInstallation:pass inViewController:self completion:^{
        NSLog(@"Done");
    }];
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

[Rest API Documentation](http://www.passslot.com/developer/api/resources)

This is the REST API links for all the Passlot API and let me know if you get the Authentication?

by this url you will get the searial number

https://www.passslot.com/account/passes